# Bring the landing page out of angular2 app in index.html + how to serve different spas for mobile and desktop on same route like gmail?

Tags: javascript, angular, performance, web-frontend

I'm currently working on angular2 app in whose index.html I inject my app-root. **What i'm trying to achieve is to bring my landing page html,css,js in index.html itself and when user clicks on any of the links on the page I want the angular app to start handling that.** The reason for doing this is my angular app js payload is too big - main.js being around 500Kb. I have already performed all the optimisations and tree shaking possible. This is impacting my lcp and other metrics too much especially in mobile.

---

My Current index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Further my app-root has router-outlet for handling each of the routes.

**Update:** For solving the first case i believe we'll have to host two apps one static app which is redirected to spa just like gmail.

Comment: You might want to investigate static prerendering of your app with a tool like scullyio..

Comment: Thanks @MikeOne just learnt about JAMStack (scully) although didn't solve my problem. I was looking for a solution something like gmail. They serve static pages before logging in and then further after logging in you have a spa. From what I have figured out I'll have to deploy two separate apps with redirection from static app to spa on logging in. Further more this is far off from the question asked but how to serve different spas on same path for mobile and desktop as the gmail does ?